# php sleep y ejecutar una funcion una vez

Tags: php

Tengo una duda,
Tengo un cron que se ejecuta cada minuto y llama a una funcion, pero esa funcion necesito que se ejecute espere 20 seg y se ejecute nuevamente, es decir solo dos veces

como puedo poner un sleep(20) y que se ejecute esa función nuevamente, pero solo una vez

```
cron:
actualizar();

<?php
function actualizar(){
    //mis procesos
    //1
    //2
    sleep(20);
    //ejecutar actualizar() pero solo una vez mas
}
?>
```

me podrian ayudar por favor

saludos

Comment: Porque no ejecutas el metodo antes y despues de sleep?

Comment: Estas seguro de como funciona sleep? sabes que esto hará que el usuario espere 20 segundos con una pagina en blanco, mas los segundos que le asignes en un segundo sleep

Comment: ¿Llamar a una función desde ella misma?  No me parece una buena idea. Además lo que dices es contradictorio: el cron llama a la función **cada minuto**, pero luego en un punto tiene que esperar 20 segundos  y luego la función tiene que llamarse a ella misma, pero sólo dos veces. Estamos hablando **de la misma función**... no puede ejecutarse cada minuto y sólo dos veces al mismo tiempo, además de hacerla esperar 20 segundos. ¿No será que necesitas **dos funciones independientes**?